# Дополнить задачу

Tags: python

> **Задача**

Учитывая массив целых чисел `nums` и целое число `target`, верните индексы двух чисел так, чтобы они составляли в сумме `target`.

Вы можете предположить, что каждый вход будет иметь ровно одно решение, и вы не можете использовать один и тот же элемент дважды.

Вы можете вернуть ответ в любом порядке.

```
#Пример 1:

#Ввод: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
#Вывод: [0,1]
#Объяснение: Поскольку nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, мы возвращаем [0, 1].
#Пример 2:

#Ввод: числа = [3,2,4], цель = 6
#Вывод: [1,2]
#Пример 3:

#Ввод: числа = [3,3], цель = 6
#Вывод: [0,1]
```

**Наброски моего кода**

```
 def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] + nums[i - 1] == target: 
            x.append(nums.index(nums[i-1]))
            x.append(nums.index(nums[i]))
        else: continue
    return x
```

**Проблема**

Если вдруг попадаться массив с одинаковыми числами, и в сумме они дают `target`, то выводит массив с нулями.

**Примеры**

```
nums = [3,3]
target = 6
Output [0,0,0,0]
```

**Попытки решить**

Я пытался через итерацию

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
x = [i - 1 for i in range(len(nums)) if nums[i] + nums[i - 1] == target]
x = [i for i in range(len(nums)) if nums[i] + nums[i - 1] == target]
return x
```

Но почему-то получалось, что программа выводит последний правильный индекс.

```
nums = [3,2,4]
target = 6
Output [2]
```

Comment: Господи, ну это так элементарно делается, зачем у тебя такие сложности??? Если сумма равна X, а одно слагаемое Y, то чему равно второе слагаемое? Кстати, ты проверяешь, только два соседних элемента, и если нужные числа будут не рядом, то ты их не найдёшь.

Comment: Сделайте просто цикл в цикле. Нужно только сообразить, как ограничить внутренний цикл, чтобы индексы не пересекались. Ну и добавлять в выходной массив нужно готовые индексы, которые у вас есть, непонятно, зачем вы там что-то хитрое с ними выдумываете.